# Original Asus Wifi router firmware: how to list clients & power

Tags: wireless-networking, iot

I'm thinking to use presence detection based on phone being connected to an AP.

I am using Asus RT-AC66U with original firmware - it has best wifi performance, and router is actually a separate device, so I don't need other fancy features.

I found command 'wl', but it keeps saying that there is no network created, nor that it's associated (not surprising, given it's an AP).

Does anyone know what command to use to list all current clients&their RX power?

Available commands:

> 3ginfo.sh                   chpasswd.sh                 get_phy_status
>   mDNSResponder               psta_monitor
>   test_if_exist_share ATE                         clear
>   get_var_file_name           madwimax                    public.pem
>   test_of_var_files [                           cmp
>   grep                        md5sum                      pwd
>   test_share [[                          comgt
>   gunzip                      mdev                        radio
>   top acsd                        console                     gzip
>   minidlna                    rc                          touch
>   add_account                 cp                          halt
>   miniupnpd                   rcheck                      tr add_folder 
>   create_if_no_var_files      head                        mkdir
>   read_sms                    traceroute add_multi_routes
>   crond                       hotplug                     mke2fs
>   readlink                    traceroute6 app_base_library.sh
>   cru                         hotplug2                    mkfs.ext2
>   reboot                      true app_base_link.sh            cut
>   how_many_layer              mkfs.ext3                   renice
>   tune2fs app_base_packages.sh        date                        httpd 
>   mknod                       restart_wireless            u2ec
>   app_cancel.sh               dd                          hub-ctrl
>   mkntfs                      rm                          udevtrigger
>   app_check_folder.sh         ddns_updated                icon.ico
>   mkswap                      rmdir                       udhcpc
>   app_check_pool.sh           del_account                 icon.large.ico
>   mod_account                 rmmod                       udpxy
>   app_fsck.sh                 del_folder                  ifconfig
>   mod_folder                  robocfg                     umount
>   app_fsck_all.sh             df                          igmp
>   modem_at.sh                 route                       uname
>   app_get_field.sh            dirname                     igmpproxy
>   modem_autoapn.sh            rsasign_check               unzip
>   app_init_run.sh             disk_monitor                igs
>   modem_enable.sh             rstats                      updown.sh
>   app_install.sh              disk_remove                 infosvr
>   modem_status.sh             run_app_script              uptime
>   app_move_to_pool.sh         dmesg                       init
>   modem_stop.sh               run_pptpd                   uqmi
>   app_remove.sh               dnsmasq
>   initial_all_var_file        modify_if_exist_new_folder  run_telnetd
>   usb_modeswitch app_set_enabled.sh          du
>   initial_folder_list         modprobe                    scsi-start
>   usb_notify app_stop.sh                 e2fsck
>   initial_var_file            more                        scsi-stop
>   usbled app_switch.sh               eapd                        inotify
>   mount                       sdparm                      usbtest.sh
>   app_update.sh               ebtables                    insmod
>   mt-daapd                    sed                         usleep
>   app_upgrade.sh              echo                        ionice
>   mtd-erase                   send_sms                    vconfig arp
>   egrep                       ip                          mtd-unlock
>   service                     vi arpstorm                    ejusb
>   ip6tables                   mtd-write                   set_permission
>   vsftpd ash                         emf
>   ip6tables-restore           mv                          setconsole
>   wanduck asus_lp                     env
>   ip6tables-save              nas                         setup_dnsmq
>   watch asus_mmc                    et                          iptables
>   netstat                     setuprsa.sh                 watchdog
>   asus_sd                     ether-wake
>   iptables-restore            netstat-nat                 sh
>   wc asus_sg                     expr
>   iptables-save               networkmap                  sigmon
>   webdav_client asus_sr                     ez-ipupdate
>   kill                        nice                        sleep
>   webs_update.sh asus_tty                    fdisk
>   killall                     nmbd                        smbd
>   webs_upgrade.sh asus_usb_interface          fgrep
>   klogd                       nohup                       smbpasswd
>   wget asus_usbbcm                 find
>   l2tp-control                nslookup                    snooper
>   which asusdiscovery               find_modem_node.sh          l2tpd
>   ntp                         sort                        wimaxc
>   asuswebstorage              find_modem_type.sh          led_ctrl
>   ntpclient                   strings                     wimaxd
>   auto_macclone               firmware_check              less
>   nvram                       swapoff                     wl autodet
>   flock                       lighttpd                    odhcp6c
>   swapon                      wlcconnect awk
>   free                        lighttpd-arpping            openssl
>   switchmode                  wlconf basename
>   free_caches                 lighttpd-monitor            openvpn
>   sync                        wlcscan bcrelay
>   fsck.ext2                   lld2d                       ots
>   sysinfo                     wpa_cli blkid
>   fsck.ext3                   lld2d.conf                  pc
>   syslogd                     wpa_supplicant brctl
>   fsck.minix                  lld2d.rtac66r               pc_block
>   tail                        wps_monitor busybox
>   fsync                       lminus                      pidof
>   tar                         wpsaide cat
>   gctwimax                    ln                          ping
>   tc                          write_3g_ppp_conf chat
>   gencert.sh                  logger                      ping6
>   tcpcheck                    write_smb_conf check_spectrum.sh
>   get_account_list            login                       pppd
>   telnetd                     write_webdav_conf chk_app_state
>   get_all_folder              lpd                         pppoe-relay
>   test                        zcat chkntfs
>   get_apps_name               lplus                       pptpctrl
>   test_disk1                  zcip chmod
>   get_folder_list             ls                          pptpd
>   test_disk2 chown                       get_permission
>   lsmod                       printf                      test_endian
>   chpasswd                    get_phy_speed               lsusb
>   ps                          test_if_exist_account

Comment: Does it have `iw`?

Comment: Would be so easy if it had :-) I'll update the OP with list of available commands.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I figured this out. The one-liner below does the job:

```
wl -i eth2 assoclist | cut -d' ' -f2 | while read MAC; do PWR=\`wl -i eth2 rssi \$MAC\`; echo \$MAC \$PWR; done
```

*wl -i  assoclist* lists all clients associated with interface provided with *-i*; in this router, eth2 is the 5 GHz band.

*cut -d' ' -f2* to select only MAC addresses.

Then, for each MAC address, *wl -i  rssi*  provides current power utilized by given client.

Hope this helps someone. I'm using this to locate where in the house is my cellphone - if in bedroom, then the reading light on the couch is shut off :-)

Comment: Better than reverse tick it's to use `$()`, as: `wl -i eth2 assoclist | cut -d' ' -f2 | while read MAC; do PWR=$(wl -i eth2 rssi $MAC); echo $MAC $PWR; done`